c# test for delete Book method
my book service's delete method looks like:
public void deleteBookById(Guid id)
{

    var book = this.applicationDbContext.Books.Find(id);
    if (book == null)
        throw new InvalidOperationException($"Book with id {id} does not exist");
    this.applicationDbContext.Remove(book);
    this.applicationDbContext.SaveChanges();
}

and my test for this, looks like:
[Fact]
public void DeleteBookById_BookExists_BookIsDeleted()
{
    var bookId1 = Guid.NewGuid();
    var bookId2 = Guid.NewGuid();

    var books = new List<Book>
    {
        new Book
        {
            Id = bookId1,
            Name = "Book 1",
            Price = 10,
            Author = new Author { Name = "Author 1" },
            Categories = new List<Category> { new Category { Name = "Category 1" } }
        },
        new Book
        {
            Id = bookId2,
            Name = "Book 2",
            Price = 20,
            Author = new Author { Name = "Author 2" },
            Categories = new List<Category> { new Category { Name = "Category 2" } }
        }
    };

    var queryable = books.AsQueryable();
    mockBooks.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
    mockBooks.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
    mockBooks.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
    mockBooks.As<IQueryable<Book>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
    mockContext.Setup(c => c.Books).Returns(mockBooks.Object);

    bookService.deleteBookById(bookId1);
    var result1 = bookService.getBookById(bookId1);
    Assert.Null(result1);

    var result2 = bookService.getBookById(bookId2);
    Assert.NotNull(result2);
}


The test fails for result1 as:
"Message: 
  System.InvalidOperationException : Book with id a3597441-548e-49b0-8e15-e86b10926e85 does not exist

Stack Trace: 
  BookService.deleteBookById(Guid id) line 117
  BookServiceTests.DeleteBookById_BookExists_BookIsDeleted() line 153"

Can you help me reasoning why? Being stuck for hours.
I want to do it with Moq, but don't know how to properly solve it, tried in different ways as well.
Thank you!

You don't write what applicationDbContext is, but I'm guessing that it's some kind of ORM (EF?). If so, using Moq or any similar kind of Test Double library like FakeItEasy, NSubstitute, etc. is not a good idea. See here for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79094142/126014

Try this approach using a dbcontext fixture
public sealed class DbContextFixture : IDisposable
{
    public readonly SomeContext _context;

    public DbContextFixture()
    {
        var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SomeContext>()
            .UseInMemoryDatabase("Test_SomeContext_Database").Options;
        _context = new SomeContext(options);
        
        
        _context.Books.AddRange(new [] {book1, book2,someBookObjectThatIAmExpecting});
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
}


private readonly DbContextFixture _dbContextFixture;

var _repository = new BooksRepository(_dbContextFixture._context);

_repository.deleteBookById(someBookObjectThatIAmExpecting.Id);



Please try to provide some explanation as well, like why did you use in memory database, etc.
